# load 3 more items [JS]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand these few strings of JS code that basically define the function that once clicked on the button, 3 other elements are loaded on the page (if there are any).

Although I have read the documentation I don't understand this line

```
boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
```

this is the complete code

```js
let loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.packages .load-more .btn'); //seleziono il primo elem con questa classe
let currentItem = 3; // # offerte caricate dopo il click  

loadMoreBtn.onclick = () =>{
   let boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.packages .box-container .box')]; //salvo in boxes tutti gli elem che hanno questa classe
   for (var i = currentItem; i < currentItem + 3; i++){ 
      boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';  
   };
   currentItem += 3;
   if(currentItem >= boxes.length){
      loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you provided is using javascript to modify the CSS properties of an element. If you are interested about different display options, check out the [CSS display syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#syntax).

So basically what your snippet does: when you click on the load more button, it will set the `display: inline-block` on the next 3 boxes in the list. If there are no more boxes, the load more button will become hidden (`display: none`)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that you're running the code inside a [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), which is used for iterating through elements one-by-one. `boxes[i]` is the element being referred to at that point in the loop.

The 'element.style.display' part is setting a [CSS property](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css3-properties.php) of that element. In this case, it's setting the `display` property to ['inline-block'](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp), which will make elements show up side-by-side (as apposed to, perhaps, ['block'](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), which would instead make new elements show up below the `block`'ed item).

I've given a breakdown of what's happening below by adding comments before most lines:

```
// Grab the clickable button.
let loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.packages .load-more .btn');

// We start counting from the third item. I guess we're assuming some items
// are already visible?
let currentItem = 3;

// This function is called when the button is clicked.
loadMoreBtn.onclick = () => {
  // This find all elements that match the classes 'packages', 'box-container', and 'box'
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.packages .box-container .box');

  // This is using a spread operator to place our elements inside an array.
  let boxes = [ ...allElements ];

  // Loop through all the items we matched using querySelectorAll above. We
  // start counting at whatever `currentItem` is. The loop will keep running
  // until `i` is 3 less than `currentItem` (or not loop at all if that
  // condition is already met).
  for (let i = currentItem; i < currentItem + 3; i++) {
    // Display the element.
    boxes[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }

  currentItem += 3;
  if (currentItem >= boxes.length) {
    // Hide the button if there are no more elements to loop through.
    loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
  }
// [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically sets the `display` property of that element to [`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp). This can be done with CSS (by setting `display: inline-block;`) or with JavaScript by setting changing the [`element.style.display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) to `inline-block`.